# Joining two tables together in one database

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I have a question which is how to get information from one tables and then with that info e.g. a name and then query the database to tell me a value in table 2.

So in short I have  a friend system going but I cant get the pictures for that user because it is in another table. I can get his name but i can not get his picture. So how do you get his picture which is in table 1 and the name is in table 2.

```
table 1
name Users

id    username  password       Email          picture                   theme  
1      bob       dabsd2323ty     hjas@hsdf      uploads/adsda.png       themes/theme1.png
2      fred        dabsd2323ty     hjas@hsdf      uploads/adsda.png       themes/theme1.png


table 2
name Friends

id  sender    receiver  checked  
1     bob      fred       2
```

2 means he has checked it and accepted it.

so i can get the name from table 2 but i dont know how to get the picture for the user from table 1

Comment: Sorry if I ask, but are the two tables in two distinct databases?

Comment: They are in the same database

Comment: ok, sorry, I misunderstood the sentence "...then query the other database to tell me a value in table 2."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic JOIN query. Whose picture do you want, the sender's or the receiver's? Let's get the picture for the receiver:

```
SELECT sender, receiver, picture
FROM Friends JOIN Users ON(receiver = username)
WHERE checked = 2;
```

If you want a specific user only, add the condition `sender = 'Jim'` or something like that to the query.

You can also JOIN a table twice. Suppose you want to get the picture of both the sender *and* the receiver:

```
SELECT sender, receiver, U1.picture AS senderpicture, U2.picture AS receiverpicture
FROM Friends
     JOIN Users AS U1 ON(sender   = U1.username)
     JOIN Users AS U2 ON(receiver = U2.username)
WHERE U2.checked = 2;
```

Comment: I don't Really get it why are you selecting picture from Friends?

Comment: I'm not. I'm selecting from `Friends JOIN Users`!

Comment: It's not just `Friends`... It's `Friends` joined to `Users` where conditions expressed in bracers are satisfied.

Comment: You should add aliases for the tables, or at least prepend the table names to the columns, otherwise you will hit an ambiguous column name type error.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: You are doing a `JOIN`, therefore _all_ the column names must be preceded with the table name or the table alias.

Comment: @Shef: he has not set an alias on `Friends` so no need for that table's column names to be preceded with `Friends.` (although it would be good practice.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.PICTURE
FROM TABLE2 T2
JOIN TABLE1 T1
ON T1.USERNAME = T2.SENDER
```

Comment: +1. You have provided a good answer, but you sure have a thing with caps, don't you? :D

Answer (score 0):

You need a join, probably a left join:

SELECT cols, you, want FROM Friends LEFT JOIN Users ON
 Friends.username=Users.username;